# X-editable events when creating content with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, append, x-editable

I have button which adds new row to table. That content contains elements using [X-editable](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/index.html). Everything else (e.g. editing X-editable fields) works fine exept X-editable events. I'm trying to use following code but nothing happens.

```
$('.editable').on('save', function(e, params) { 
    console.log('test' + params.newValue);
});
```

After refreshing the page everything works fine. What would be the problem?

Thanks in advance!